# Next.js Cannot read property 'xx' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a simple quiz app, using react context and multistep form. Here is my code handling form data

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const QuizContext = createContext();

export default function QuizProvider({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const setQuizValues = (values) => {
    setData((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      ...values,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <QuizContext.Provider value={{ data, setQuizValues }}>
      {children}
    </QuizContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useQuizData = () => useContext(QuizContext);
```

Now, going into my first step component, I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'setQuizValues' of undefined:

```
import { Card } from "../../stories/Card";
import { useQuizData } from "../../context/index"

export const TacoCathegories = ({quizStep, prevQuizStep, nextQuizStep}) => {
  const { setQuizValues } = useQuizData();

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    setQuizValues(values);
    prevQuizStep();
    nextQuizStep();
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-24 px-4 bg-white sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="mt-24 space-y-12 lg:space-y-0 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-x-8">
         <Card />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am actually going through the same steps I went through for a similar project.

Comment: Are you wrapping `TacoCathegories` - or any of its parent components - with `QuizProvider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `useQuizData` hook is returning `undefined`. This would be the case if you haven't included a provider for the quiz context above the component calling this hook, because the default value for the context is `undefined`. Try wrapping your component tree inside `<QuizProvider> ... </QuizProvider>`.

Comment: const { setQuizValues } = useQuizData; I did that and it worked. Why? Well, I still don't know, if data gets collected, but at least the rest works ...

Comment: in _app.js I've wrapped it and it worked, thanks!